# I want to draw a clock in SurfaceView , but the pointer is copied each three times

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to know why the pointer been copied

All of the pointer will turn and each three times that the point will be copied

If you can tell me in detail the principle will help a lot

```
private Canvas canvas;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private void initSurface() {
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int time = 0;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.line2);
            while (true) {
                synchronized (holder) {
                    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        canvas.save();
                        canvas.rotate(360 / 60 * time,
                                Utils.getScreenWidthPx(MainActivity.this) / 2,
                                Utils.getScreenHeightPx(MainActivity.this) / 2
                        );
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap
                                , Utils.getScreenWidthPx(MainActivity.this) / 2
                                , Utils.getScreenHeightPx(MainActivity.this) / 2
                                , null);
                        canvas.restore();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    time++;
                    if (time == 60) {
                        time = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (canvas != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

[the clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFszQ.png)

Comment: There was no duplication of method calls

Comment: Through the test log,The method body once per second